# Package RTextTools loaded but facing Error: could not find function "create_matrix"

Tags: r

```
install.packages('RTextTools')
library(RTextTools)

data("NYTimes", package='RTextTools')
head(NYTimes)

timesMat <- create_matrix(NYTimes$Title)
```

The package is installed and I can view the "NYTimes" data set but the `create_matrix` call throws an error that it can't find the function.

One more thing: call to `library(RTextTools)` gives the following error messages:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[i]]) :    there is no package called ‘slam’ Error: package or
>   namespace load failed for ‘RTextTools’

Any help appreciated...

Comment: `install.packages("slam")` and try again ...

Comment: install.packages("slam")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘slam’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)

Comment: please help..just started learning and practicing R last 2 months..want to learn around Text Analytics but facing issue with package installing

Comment: Slam depends on R ≥ 3.3.1 (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html), you have to upgrade your R version.